# error_reporting 22519

Tags: php, php5

Hola a todos previamente hice una [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/194193/problemas-con-redirecci%C3%B3n-a-la-hora-de-generar-un-archivo-excel-en-php), la cual lamentablemente no fué respondida, lo unico bueno es que es posible que el error sea del servidor he puesto que me imprima los errores con `var_dump(error_reporting(E_ALL));` pero, en si devuelve un número `22519` y no sabría que significa, alguien me puede ayudar? ya que es para el trabajo, y pues desearía saber como corregirlo sin necesidad de tocar el servidor posiblemente.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Al hacer `var_dump(error_reporting(E_ALL));` te está devolviendo el nivel de reporte anteriormente establecido, aquí puedes ver las máscaras válidas,  http://php.net/manual/es/errorfunc.constants.php , `error_reporting` establece el nivel de reporte, pero en si no es quien te muestra el error, lo mejor en cuanto errores es revisar el Log.

Comment: lo veo difícil ya que no puede tocar nada del servidor :( pero gracias igualmente